# Downloading most recent stock prices

Tags: equities, quote

I would like to download (from Google) the most recent prices for a series of stocks. I have created a portfolio at Google and I can click on "Download to Spreadsheet".  That works.

But I would like to automate the process so that I can obtain the spreadsheet using R.  I did this previously from Yahoo with the code:
  read.csv("http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/DRRX,AAPL,AMZN")
However, I can't figure out the comparable code to download from Google.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

R is very useful for downloading data from `Yahoo/Google` . Here is an example for downloading from `Google Finance` :

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("DRRX;AAPL;AMZN", from="2014-01-01", to="2014-11-20", src='google')
```

Just adjust the `from` and `to` dates as needed. This will download the `OHLCV` data from google finance to your R global environment.

Answer (score 0):

I explored this further and following that the following works:

require("RCurl")
STOCKS <- paste("AAPL", "BIDU", "AMAZ", collapse=",")
STRING  <- paste0("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDU,IXIC,DRRX,", paste0(STOCKS, collapse=","))
TEMP    <- getURL(STRING)

Then, one needs to do some editing (a combination of strsplit and gsub) on the output.